# map/set iterator is not dereferencable C++ map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

Please, have a look at my code.

```
int main () {
    Program* allcommand = new Program;
    allcommand->addCommand("add", new Add);
    allcommand->addCommand("convert", new Convert);
    allcommand->addCommand("exit", new Exit);
    allcommand->addCommand("help", new Help);
    allcommand->addCommand("show", new Show);
    allcommand->addCommand("modify", new Modify);

    std::string input;
    Command* obj;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "\nCommand >> ";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        std::map<std::string, Command*> :: iterator it;
        std::vector<std::string> parsedinput = allcommand->parse(input);

        it = allcommand->getCommands().find(parsedinput[0]);
        obj = it->second;

        obj->start(parsedinput);
        delete obj;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It registers commands to a map which holds its command name and pointer to its class. 
This compiles without problems but when I enter a command, it crashes with "map/set iterator not dereferencable". I am new to maps (few minutes) so please help.

EDIT. Ok I found that the problem is not in main... Here is code of Program class (some of it)

```
    void Program::addCommand(std::string command1, Command* obj) {
    m_allCommands[command1] = obj;
}

std::map<std::string, Command*> Program::getCommands () {
    return m_allCommands;
}
```

I think the problem is here, because after i register commands in main, I cannot cout the name of any command (same problem)

Comment: Try to check `it` after this `it = allcommand->getCommands().find(parsedinput[0]);` line.

Comment: Same problem, when i removed everything after that line and tried to cout it->first, which is string

Comment: I mean, try to check if `it` is not same with `allcommand->getCommands().end()`, i.e., check if command exists. Also try to use debugger and find the line, that throws the error.

Comment: Be careful with your `delete obj;`, in the current code it leaves a dangling pointer in the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::map<std::string, Command*> Program::getCommands () {
    return m_allCommands;
}
```

returns a copy of the `m_allcommands` map. So when you do:

```
it = allcommand->getCommands().find(parsedinput[0]);
```

You get an iterator on the temporary object returned by `allcommand->getCommands()` that gets destroyed when the assignment is done. Therefore it points to nothing.

Change `getCommands()` to:

```
std::map<std::string, Command*>& Program::getCommands () {
    return m_allCommands;
}
```

or even better:

```
const std::map<std::string, Command*>& Program::getCommands () const {
    return m_allCommands;
}
```

Comment: Great man, this worked, thanks very much(still can't believe I missed that) anyways this opened another problem. OK first when I enter command, it works but when I enter second command it crashes (Dont know if it is good idea to ask that here)

Comment: Don't delete `obj`. Your command object need to still be alive in your internal map if you enter the same command twice. The place to delete your command objects is in `Program::~Program()`

Answer (score 2):

After a call to `find()` you need to check if

```
if(it == allcommand->getCommands().end()) {
   //Not Found
} else {
   obj = it->second;
   obj->start(parsedinput);
}
```

Comment: Please, have a look at the same code again (I added some info)

Comment: Does it happen the first time or the second time, as someone said above, you shouldn't be calling `delete obj` after you use a command as then that command will be gone forever. You haven't posted enough code. If you use a debugger it should be able to point you to the line where the invalid dereference occured

Comment: The first time, that's why I am not paying attention. OK debugger shows that the problem is the line if(it == allcommand->getCommands().end()) {